# How to add strings to cuckoo filter?

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap

I am running a modified version of example provided at Cuckoo filter repository: https://github.com/efficient/cuckoofilter/blob/master/example/test.cc

I want to add strings to cuckoo filter. Although the string is added but when I check if it exists in the filter, it always returns false. Can anyone point out what's wrong with my approach?

```
size_t total_items  = 1000000;
CuckooFilter<string, 12> filter(total_items);

// Insert items to this cuckoo filter
string temp1 = "sample";
if (filter.Add(temp1) != cuckoofilter::Ok) {
        cout<<"not added"<<endl;
}    

// Check if previously inserted items are in the filter
string temp2 = "sample";
assert(filter.Contain(temp2) == cuckoofilter::Ok);
```

The assertion should be true but it is false in this case. Why?

Answer (score 2):

A quick glance at the source of https://github.com/efficient/cuckoofilter/blob/master/src/cuckoofilter.h#L65 reveals that it uses a function

```cpp
inline void GenerateIndexTagHash(const ItemType &item, size_t* index, uint32_t* tag) const
{
    std::string hashed_key = HashUtil::SHA1Hash(
        (const char*) &item,
        sizeof(item)
    );

// ... rest is skipped for brevity

}
```

to generate an initial index and a fingerprint (tag) of the item. The problem is that it **hashes an actual object** passed. To simplify, it does this:

```
// Your filter.Add(temp1) inside does this
HashUtil::SHA1Hash((const char*) &temp1, sizeof(temp1));

// Your filter.Contain(temp2) inside does this
HashUtil::SHA1Hash((const char*) &temp2, sizeof(temp2));
```

Basically, it hashes two completely different objects which, as expected, generate different hashes and map to different buckets.

For it to work in your case it would need to call **HashUtil::SHA1Hash()** in a way that hashes the actual string data, that is:

```
// It should do something like this
HashUtil::SHA1Hash(
    temp1.c_str(), // <-- notice we pass a pointer to an actual character data rather than a pointer to an instance of a std::string()
    temp1.length()
);


HashUtil::SHA1Hash(
    temp2.c_str(), // <-- notice we pass a pointer to an actual character data rather than a pointer to an instance of a std::string()
    temp2.length()
);
```

This should answer your *Why?* question. As for the

> Can anyone point out what's wrong with my approach?

There is nothing really  wrong with your approach per-se it just doesn't work as you might've expected, because a library does not support such a use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I modified the source to use SuperFastHash instead of SHA1/MD5 and it worked.